# Parse date from string in SQL with pattern variation

Tags: sql

I need to be able to extract out a date from a string in SQL. I have a solution that will work with a specific format, but the format can vary slightly, so I need to adjust the pattern to support the variations.

Here is what I have currently:

```
DECLARE @Subject NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Some example text- 09/30/18 and more text         1622'

SELECT
    ISNULL(
        TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(@Subject, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', @Subject), 8) AS DATETIME),
            DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) AS SomeDate
```

This does work when the date is 09/30/18, but fails when it is 9/30/18, 09/2/18, and 09/30/2018.

Is there a known pattern that is able to support these variations?

Comment: honestly, sql is not ideal at string parsing. maybe consider a clr function, or a more procedural function to look for all of the variations you need?

Comment: @Jeremy I agree. Instead of parsing this using SQL, I will be shifting the responsibility to C#. I am still curious if there is a solution that involves only SQL though.

Comment: you just have to code each case individually, test to ensure that you've covered all cases, and you're good to go.

Comment: Try combining `SET DATEFORMAT` with `TRY_CAST + DATE`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the tag for the relevant rdbms (I'm guessing SQL Server based on syntax) and all the different formats you might need to handle.